# IndexedDB object keys: does the size matter?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm about to store a lot of objects in an indexeddb object store. All the objects have the same structure, something like `{somekey: xxx, somevalue: yyy}`.

Does the length of the objet keys impact the size of the stored data ? For instance, if I change the structure to `{s: xxxx, v: yyyy}`, should I expect a better footprint in the object store with the current browsers ?

I couldn't find any information on this in anywhere in the standard, so I guess it's up to the browsers implementation to internally use a dictionary or not, and I'd like to learn about how it's currently  implemented, and whether it's worthy optimization to reduce the size of the store object's keys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will impact it. But at least for reasonably sized keys, one character vs 10 or 20 characters is not going to make any difference in performance unless you're at a very large scale (millions of records). Most of the implementations (including chrome, which I can speak for) do store the full object including key names, but indexes only store the "keypath" once..

Meaning that {"foo": "bar"} probably takes on the order of ~12 bytes to store (roughly 4 bytes for each string plus some type info overhead, but a subsequent index on "foo" will only store "baz".

{"foobarbaz": "helloworld"} probably takes ~23 bytes to store. Really I would expect under most circumstances your own data should eclipse the overhead of key length and trying to shorten your keys to save a few bytes is premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however my question was more about storage footprint than performance. For instance, using your example, if I store {"foobarbaz": "helloworld"} twenty times, are current implementation using ~23bytes x 20, or is the key being stored in a dictionary, and referenced as such in the structure (implying that long key names being used in all the objects do not impact significatively the storage quota)

Comment: Sorry, I think I may have misnamed something, when I say key, I mean property names in the structured object being stored...

Comment: yes, I was talking about storage footprint, and usually yes, the object is stored 20 times, at least in the implementations I'm aware of.